# Build Advanced Programming In The Unix Environment source code for a 64-bit OS

Tags: c, linux, unix

Building the source code for [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/) (APUE) on my computer ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), 64 bit) fails. I get an error:

```
ipp.h:121:17: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
 #define status u.st
```

A bit of searching told me that the code was intended for 32-bit architectures. How can I modify this to build successfully? I really don't want to have to install another OS just to use the APUE header.

Comment: Enable the `multilib` repository in `/etc/pacman.conf` and install `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Comment: The mirrors for the gcc-multilib packages all 404.
Keith, I'm using the second edition.

Comment: @Blender: Okay, update: one of the mirrors works, but fails to install.
`error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))`